# How can I setup html template in hbs templating engine in nestjs application in the views folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, handlebars.js, nestjs, templating-engine

I Have images , css , and js files in my public folder and In my views folder I have handlebars(hbs) formatted files in the nest.js application.
How can I access images , css , and files in .hbs files.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to handle hbs files in nest.js, you should install hbs moulde using command npm install hbs.
after installation your problem will be solved

Comment: Although this answer was downvoted before I reverted the counter, it still conforms to the Nest documentation.